# Little speedup when porting Python code to Cython

Tags: python, performance, numpy, cython, cythonize

I have some python code which uses numpy which computes gradient of a function and this is a big bottleneck in my application. So, my initial attempt was to try to use `Cython` to improve the performance.

So, using online guides, I was able to port this to Cython easily but got a very moderate speedup around 15%. The function contains many loops and I was hoping that Cython would give a much better improvement.

The Cython code looks as follows. The following are helper functions that only get called from Cython.

```
cimport numpy as np
cimport cython

@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
@cython.nonecheck(False)
cdef cget_cubic_bspline_weight(double u):
    u = fabs(u)
    if u < 2.0:
        if u < 1.0:
            return 2.0 / 3.0 - u ** 2 + 0.5 * u ** 3
        else:
            return ((2.0 - u) ** 3) / 6.0

    return 0.0

@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
@cython.nonecheck(False)
cdef cget_cubic_spline_first_der_weight(double u):
    cdef double o = u
    u = fabs(u)
    cdef double v
    if u < 2.0:
        if u < 1.0:
            return (1.5 * u - 2.0) * o
        else:
            u -= 2.0
            v = -0.5 * u * u
            if o < 0.0:
                return -v
            return v

    return 0.0;
```

The following is the main function that computes the gradient.

```
@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
@cython.nonecheck(False)
cpdef gradient_2d(np.ndarray[double, ndim=2, mode="c"] reference,
                  np.ndarray[double, ndim=2, mode="c"] warped,
                  np.ndarray[double, ndim=5, mode="fortran"] warped_gradient,
                  np.ndarray[double, ndim=5, mode="fortran"] result_gradient,
                  double[:] entropies,
                  np.ndarray[double, ndim=2, mode="c"] jhlog,
                  np.ndarray[double, ndim=2, mode="fortran"] reflog,
                  np.ndarray[double, ndim=2, mode="fortran"] warlog,
                  int[:] bins,
                  int height, int width):

    war_x = warped_gradient[..., 0]
    war_y = warped_gradient[..., 1]

    res_x = result_gradient[..., 0]
    res_y = result_gradient[..., 1]
    nmi = (entropies[0] + entropies[1]) / entropies[2]

    for y in range(height):
        for x in range(width):
            ref = reference[x, y]
            war = warped[x, y]
            jd = [0.0] * 2
            rd = [0.0] * 2
            wd = [0.0] * 2

            for r in range(int(ref - 1.0), int(ref + 3.0)):
                if (-1 < r and r < bins[0]):
                    for w in range(int(war - 1.0), int(war + 3.0)):
                        if (-1 < w and w < bins[1]):
                            c = cget_cubic_bspline_weight(ref - float(r)) * \
                        cget_cubic_spline_first_der_weight(war - float(w))

                            jl = jhlog[r, w]
                            rl = reflog[r, 0]
                            wl = warlog[0, w]

                            jd[0] += c * war_x[x, y] * jl
                            rd[0] += c * war_x[x, y] * rl
                            wd[0] += c * war_x[x, y] * wl

                            jd[1] += c * war_y[x, y] * jl
                            rd[1] += c * war_y[x, y] * rl
                            wd[1] += c * war_y[x, y] * wl


            res_x[x, y] = (rd[0] + wd[0] - nmi * jd[0]) / (entropies[2] * entropies[3])
            res_y[x, y] = (rd[1] + wd[1] - nmi * jd[1]) / (entropies[2] * entropies[3])
```

Now, I call this as:

```
speed.gradient_2d(self.rdata, self.wdata, warped_grad_image,
                  result_gradient.data, self.entropies,
                  self.jhlog, self.reflog, self.warlog, self.bins,
                  int(self.rdata.shape[1]), int(self.rdata.shape[0]))
```

Everything except the last 2 parameters are numpy arrays and are as described in the cython function signature. The python code is pretty much the same and I can post it if you want but it is basically really the same.

I compiled the whole thing with the `setup.py` as:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize
import numpy

ext = Extension("speed",
                sources=["perf/speed.pyx"],
                include_dirs=[numpy.get_include()],
                language="c++",
                libraries=[],
                extra_link_args=[])

setup(ext_modules = cythonize([ext]))
```

Again, because I have so many loops in my code, I was under the impression that the Cython version would be much faster but I only get 15% improvement. I followed this guide for the implementation: http://docs.cython.org/en/latest/src/userguide/numpy_tutorial.html and as far as I can tell I did pretty much everything it recommends. Any suggestions on what I could try next would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: you should factorize/pre-compute some values so they would be computed only once. Maybe give it a shot on http://codereview.stackexchange.com to see if some ppl want to try to optimize your code

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Thanks for the suggestion about the codereview site. I implemented a C/C++ equivalant and that was much faster, so that is why I am baffled why the cython one is so much slower. I will cross post there.

Comment: I suppose that Cython still performs array boundary checking, which explains a bit. Generated code isn't as good as manually written C code.

Comment: No, I have set bounds checking to be off: 
`@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
@cython.nonecheck(False)`

Comment: I'm not a cython expert but accessing a list item uses a function call, whereas `a[i]` is just pointer addition with integer for C. I may be completely wrong since I don't know Cython. Maybe edit your post to show the cython generated C code?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after playing around a bit, it turns out that the main thing that will boost speed is using ctypes. Here is the modified code which offers about 13x speedup. I am leaving it here in case it will be of use to someone else. I am sure more performance can be extracted but I will be hitting diminishing returns.

```
@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
@cython.nonecheck(False)
cpdef gradient_2d(np.ndarray[double, ndim=2, mode="c"] reference,
                  np.ndarray[double, ndim=2, mode="c"] warped,
                  np.ndarray[double, ndim=5, mode="fortran"] warped_gradient,
                  np.ndarray[double, ndim=5, mode="fortran"] result_gradient,
                  double[:] entropies,
                  np.ndarray[double, ndim=2, mode="c"] jhlog,
                  np.ndarray[double, ndim=2, mode="fortran"] reflog,
                  np.ndarray[double, ndim=2, mode="fortran"] warlog,
                  int[:] bins,
                  int height, int width):

    # As per @DavidW suggestion. See comment below.

    cdef np.ndarray[double, ndim=4, mode="fortran"] war_x = warped_gradient[..., 0]
    cdef np.ndarray[double, ndim=4, mode="fortran"] war_y = warped_gradient[..., 1]

    cdef np.ndarray[double, ndim=4, mode="fortran"] res_x = result_gradient[..., 0]
    cdef np.ndarray[double, ndim=4, mode="fortran"] res_y = result_gradient[..., 1]
    cdef double nmi = (entropies[0] + entropies[1]) / entropies[2]
    cdef double norm = entropies[2] * entropies[3]

    cdef double jd[2]
    cdef double rd[2]
    cdef double wd[2]

    cdef double ref
    cdef double war
    cdef double c_war_x_x_y
    cdef double c_war_y_x_y

    cdef double jl
    cdef double rl
    cdef double wl

    for y in range(height):
        for x in range(width):
            ref = reference[x, y]
            war = warped[x, y]

            jd[0] = jd[1] = 0.0
            rd[0] = rd[1] = 0.0
            wd[0] = wd[1] = 0.0

            for r in range(int(ref - 1.0), int(ref + 3.0)):
                if (-1 < r and r < bins[0]):
                    for w in range(int(war - 1.0), int(war + 3.0)):
                        if (-1 < w and w < bins[1]):
                            c = cget_cubic_bspline_weights(ref - r) * \
                            cget_cubic_spline_first_der_weights(war - w)
                            jl = jhlog[r, w]
                            rl = reflog[r, 0]
                            wl = warlog[0, w]

                            c_war_x_x_y = c * war_x[x, y]
                            c_war_y_x_y = c * war_y[x, y]

                            jd[0] += c_war_x_x_y * jl
                            rd[0] += c_war_x_x_y * rl
                            wd[0] += c_war_x_x_y * wl

                            jd[1] += c_war_y_x_y * jl
                            rd[1] += c_war_y_x_y * rl
                            wd[1] += c_war_y_x_y * wl


            res_x[x, y] = (rd[0] + wd[0] - nmi * jd[0]) / norm
            res_y[x, y] = (rd[1] + wd[1] - nmi * jd[1]) / norm
```

Comment: I'd be tempted to type `war_x` and `war_y` (and probably `res_x` and `res_y`) as a suitable array types too. I suspect you'd gain some measurable speed from that.

Comment: @DavidW Another 4 times speedup! I have updated the answer with the suggestion!

Comment: The term “ctypes” is s bit misleading in a Python context. I’d call them either “c types” or “cdef variables”.